# How can I execute and interrupt a script in a loop

Tags: shell-script

I have a script called `demo.py` First I execute the script

```
python demo.py -some arguments
```

After some time (let say 120 seconds) I interrupt it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and execute again. Can I write a bash script in order to do these steps in a loop automatically?

Comment: You got your answer, but... this is an ugly thing to do. Relying on interrupt signals (and the resulting forced exit, or signal trap) is something to avoid if possible. It's acceptable if the signal really signals something (which you cannot predict in advance). But if you know you want to exit after a specified time, it would be much better if the script itself sets its own timer and exits after that time (the timeout could be settable from commandline).

Comment: @orion - there's nothing ugly about signals - they're what terminals *(and job control)* do. I would agree though that it might be preferable if the utility could handle that setting. However, a lot of times it is not so. `bash`, for example, relies on `readline` to do most of that for it in an interactive shell.

Comment: Depends on what the script does. If it just lets the signal kill it, it may leave incomplete output to files, unremoved temporary files and so on. That's what I meant. If it traps the SIGINT and cleans up, it's ok.

Comment: @orion - Yes - definitely best practice when a script which will be creating/modifying files is run is for that script to first and foremost 1)  sanitize environment 2) seek out/create a workdir 3) trap the removal of same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python demo.py -some arguments &
( sleep 120; kill -TSTP "$!")  & 
fg %1
```

Will first background `python`, then start a backgrounded shell that `sleep`s for 120 seconds before sending `python` the `-TSTP` - or the *suspend* signal. This is not strictly identical to pressing *`CTRL+C`* - for that you'd want `kill -INT "$!"` - but I thought you might you like to be able to restore it again, as this is like doing *`CTRL+Z`* instead.

Last it `fg` *foregrounds* job ID `%1` - which, if these are the only two processes in the `jobs` table, will be `python`.

And so your `demo` runs, while a waiting `kill`er lurks in the shadows.

Here it is w/ `cat` and a 5 second wait:

```
cat & ( sleep 5; kill -TSTP "$!" )& fg %1
cat
[1] + Stopped                    cat
```

To do it in a loop you can do:

```
(kill -TSTP 0); code=$?
python demo.py -some arguments & pid=$!  
while   (sleep 120;kill -TSTP "$pid")&
        fg %1; [ "$?" = "$code" ]
do :;   done
```